# How to show in order a list of locations with geocoder?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, reverse-geocoding

I want to show the address (city and country) from a coordinate list. At first I used to reverse Geocoder but having 80 records, the application was very slow but showed the names correctly. I decided to use AsyncTask for this process but the names of the addresses do not match looks like he's picking at random and putting them on the list. What could I do? Any advice?

Comment: asynctask is the proper way to go, since the geocoder uses network operations. You simply need to make sure the proper result goes into the proper value.

Comment: I tried only display the first 4 records with coordendas in a list and see that in the last row is where the names shown, ie in the last row makes a journey from the first to the last name. And yet the process is very slow. I'm stuck in this process geocoder.

Comment: I think that the problem is in "tituloTxt.setText(city);" The names are not put in each row.